# Can PyPI serve packages directly from GitHub?

Tags: python, github, pypi

Is there any way to link a PyPI repo directly to a GitHub repo so that it makes the latest version of the files available for download instead of uploading the files every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, PyPI only serves packages uploaded to it.  `pip` can install from other sources than PyPI though:

```
pip install https://github.com/sopython/sopython-site/tarball/master

pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/sopython/sopython-site@master#egg=sopython-site
```